# Convert snake case to camel case for Spring Paging and Sorting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

The hibernate entities have the fields named in camel case, but when a DTO constructed from that entity is returned from a REST API we convert the field name to snake case.

There is a generic way to convert every DTO field into snake case with a jackson configuration like so

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
```

The issue with this is now for example, with Spring paging and sorting if we want to sort by parameter we need to pass the parameter as camel case and not as snake case.

Example:

Entity looks like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class Entity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "some_text")
  private String someText;
}
```

DTO looks like this:

```
@Data
public class EntityDTO implements Serializable {

  private UUID id;

  private String someText;
}
```

The output JSON is the following:

```
{
  "id": "80fb034a-36c1-4534-a39f-b344fa815a2d",
  "some_text": "random text"
}
```

Now if we would like to call the endpoint with a sort parameter for example:

```
/entities?sort=some_text&some_text.dir=desc
```

it will not work because the field in the entity is actually someText and not some_text which is quite confusing because the output is in snake case and not camel case.

So the general question is how to deal with this? Is there a smart way to do it? Some jackson configuration or argument handler configuration? Or do I need to manually convert every single snake case parameter to camel case?

Thank you guys in advance.

---

Comment: Jackson strategy doesn't work with `sort=some_text` because it applies to the query parameter ("sort" in our case), but not to its value ("some_text"). And it is logical behavior.

Till now I don't know how to solve the same problem as yours. Inventing solution right now.

Answer (score 3):

you the below property in application.properties file to convert Snake case to camel case.

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

Or you can annotate the attributes as below in case you map only a single class.

```
@JsonProperty("some_text")
private String someText;
```

OR annotate the entity as below

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

Comment: It`s doesn't work for me. SNAKE_CASE works fine for JSON serialization, but not for Sort

Answer (score 2):

Below I provide the solution which would solve your problem without the need for definition of mapping for each DTO field name to its corresponding DAO/entity field name. It's using constants and method of `com.google.common.base.CaseFormat` class from Google Guava library for transformation of strings in one case to another. I assume that you are extracting paging and ordering info from request in instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` class.

```java
public Page<Entity> getEntities(Pageable dtoPageable) {
    PageRequest daoPageable = PageRequest.of(
                                  dtoPageable.getPageNumber(),
                                  dtoPageable.getPageSize(),
                                  convertDtoSortToDaoSort(dtoPageable.getSort())
    );
    return entityRepository.findAll(daoPageable);
}

private Sort convertDtoSortToDaoSort(Sort dtoSort) {
    return Sort.by(dtoSort.get()
                          .map(sortOrder -> sortOrder.withProperty(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, sortOrder.getProperty())))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```